# Importing data from Excel for DateListPlot

Tags: curated-data, data, date-and-time, data-format

I am importing data from Excel and plotting it with `DateListPlot`. My code is

```
DateListPlot[{
  Join @@ Import[""][[1 ;;, 3 ;;]][[All, All, 2 ;; 3]], 
  Join @@ Import[""][[1 ;;, 3 ;;]][[All, All, 4 ;; 5]]}, 
  Joined -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> All]
```

But my problem is this works for just for the first sheet (year 2013) of the many in the same file. Sheet 2 is for Year 2012 and has the same format, and so forth. I want to get all the sheets for all the years; they are continuations of each other. Could you help me to figure out what code will do this?

Comment: offtop: `1;;` = `;;` = `All`

Comment: @Kuba thanks can you see my coding skills?!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work:

```
Import["test.xls", "Sheets"]
```

> {Sheet1, Sheet2}

```
data1 = Import["test.xls", {"Sheets", "Sheet1"}];
data2 = Import["test.xls", {"Sheets", "Sheet2"}];
all = Sort[Join[data1, data2]];
DateListPlot[all, Joined -> True]
```

But I haven't got Excel here so I can't test it.

### Edit

With lots of sheets:

```
sheets = Import["test.xls", "Sheets"]
data  =  Import["test.xls", {"Sheets", # }] & /@ sheets
```

and see how the data looks then.

Comment: thanks but what if I have 50 sheets?Please pay attention to my required format of `[[1 ;;, 3 ;;]][[All, All, 2 ;; 3]], 
[[1 ;;, 3 ;;]][[All, All, 4 ;; 5]]`

Comment: @Alex No idea what all that means... :) But once you've imported the data, just select the bits you want - that should be basic list-manipulation stuff.

Comment: It fails to import data what could be wrong?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not a doctor... :/

Comment: I am recovered :D thanks

Comment: @alex the StackExchange gods have healing powers apparently. (And thanks for the accept!)

Comment: @YES definitely!!you are welcome!